# MySQL query to search a field with JSON string

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

This might be simple enough with basic SQL or it might need a REGEXP but I've hit a brick wall.

My data is stored in a JSON string like these two examples (each in 1 field):

```
[{"id":"2","value":["1","3"]},{"id":"3","value":["1","2"]}]
```

and:

```
[{"id":"3","value":["2"]},{"id":"3","value":["1","2","5"]}]
```

I want to search for values in between those last brackets which might consist of many numbers `["1","2","5"] or just a single on ["2"]`. The beginning numbers correspond to 2 categories - the single `"id":"2"` and `"id":"3"`.

Using `%"2"%` with a simple LIKE of course matches everything. I can query by the `"id":"$var"` to return each category then use PHP to filter it through after we have the results, but the data can be quite large and I'm sure it's easy for a SQL guru.

I don't have the option to change the format of the field, it has to remain as JSON.

Any help appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think I solved it by using this: `AND extra_fields REGEXP '(.*"id":"2".*)("\[.*"1".*\]")'`. It's more to do with regular expressions than it is to do with MySQL :P

comment: (I couldn't find comment button)
This syntax becomes clearer when you learn that "extra_fields" is the name of the column in the table

Comment: would you be able to help me out on a similar issue? `'"(.*\"Reticle.*\":\"*.'.$reticle2.'.*\")"'` is what my `REGEXP` looks like and its a parameter to bind `:reticle`. The query works but no results.

Comment: Just want to add that these sorts of queries can't be indexed, so if you're using this is in a high-traffic website, such implementations can result in big performance hits.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL it is really simple, because you only need to identify the last opening bracket.
This can you do with substring index.

Maybe your table called test, and your field with the string called text - this should work

```
select text from (select substring_index(text,'[',-1) as text from test) as new where text like '%5%'**
```

If you have a text between 2 unique delimiters, maybe u find [this tutorial](http://infofreund.de/mysql-select-substring-2-different-delimiters/) helpful