# Speed up mysql search with filter

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make a good mysql query to make as fast as possible.

I have some users like this :

```
+-------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|id     | name        | params                                                        |
+-------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|1      | Joey        | a:3:{s:8:"is_legit";i:1;s:3:"age";i:15;s:9:"registred";i:0;}  |
|2      | Cloe        | a:2:{s:6:"length";i:185;s:9:"registred";i:1;}                 |
|3      | Mark        | a:2:{s:6:"length";i:185;s:11:"valid_email";i:1;}              |
+-------+-------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For example for Joey's params I make a serialize of

```
array (
"is_legit" => 1,
"age" => 15,
"registred" => 0
)
```

I have a filter bar and I would like to know if there is a way to make the query faster than a simple `%LIKE%`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL query to search a field with JSON string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168872/mysql-query-to-search-a-field-with-json-string)

Comment: REGEX is not really a solution I think. Maybe there is a better way ?

Comment: Where are your indexes on the table?

Comment: @anasbud Not really a solution because you've tried it?

Comment: My index is the "id" column.
I just thought that maybe there a better solution than this.

Comment: I think the real solution is to store the data in a more sensible format -- maybe a table with key/value pairs. You're never going to get a good performance search with data in the format you've got.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off changing your schema to an Entity-Attribute-Value model:
[Entity Attribute Value Database vs. strict Relational Model Ecommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870808/entity-attribute-value-database-vs-strict-relational-model-ecommerce-question)

What you're trying to do is better suited for a Column Family Store (like Cassandra), or a Document Database (like MongoDB).

The only sure-fire way (without changing your schema), is to do a greedy search, and then actually filter the exact matches in the application logic.

Comment: Is REGEX faster than LIKE for my case ?

Comment: Probably not. Neither is ideal, but I'd guess `LIKE` to be substantially faster.