# mysql query to search inside column containing json array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I've a column in MySQL database in this format:

```
{
"monday":[["11:00","19:30"]],
"tuesday":[["11:00","19:30"]],
"wednesday":[["11:00","19:30"]],
"thursday":[["11:00","19:30"]],
"friday":[["11:00","20:00"]],
"saturday":[["11:00","20:00"]],
"sunday":[["11:00","20:00"]]
}
```

Let's suppose that I would like to know if the restaurant is open now that is friday and is 14:00

how can I make this query? Is there a way?

I tried this query

```
SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE field_name REGEXP '"key_name":"([^"]*)key_word([^"]*)"';
```

But I would like to search first for day and then between hours. I'm not able to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: This is why you don't store data as json

Comment: You can use MySQL's REGEXP to search the data: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Comment: what do you mean John? I got this data from an external source.

Comment: Thank You Karl.. I know this.. but I'm not able to create a query

Comment: If you know this, then surely you've TRIED something, what have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL query to search a field with JSON string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168872/mysql-query-to-search-a-field-with-json-string)

Comment: SELECT id FROM table_name WHERE field_name REGEXP '"key_name":"([^"]*)key_word([^"]*)"';

Comment: Do not post code in the comment section.  Please edit your question instead.

Comment: Not a duplicate, it's different type of query. I've to search first by day and then between hours. But I don't know how to do that

Comment: The logic behind the query remains the same, you just need to tweak and adjust it for you own needs.

Comment: I can't understand how to use < and > because I've to check if the value of the hour (14:00) is between 11:00 and 20:00. I don't know how to do that with regex. That query is useful if I've to find a specific information.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way search that type of data with a select query. It would be much faster to restructure your database using proper column types. If you are insistent about keeping your current database layout, you will need to write a a sql function so you can correctly parse the data and return what you want.

Comment: WRONG: You can use REGEXP to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It is far from efficient and I discourage you to use this snippet, but here is something that do what you want.

```
select json
, openday
, start
, end
, opening
, startopen
, endopen
from (
    select json
    , openday
    , start
    , end
    , opening
    , left(opening, locate(',',opening) - 1) as startopen
    , right(opening, locate(',',opening) - 1) as endopen
    from (
        select json
        , openday
        , start
        , end
        , replace(substring(json, start, end - start), '"','') as opening
        from (
            select json
            , openday
            , locate('[[', json, openday) + 2 as start
            , locate(']]', json, openday) as end 
            from (
                select json
                , locate('friday', json) as openday
                from `test-regexp`
            ) as a
        ) as b
    ) as c
) as d
where '14:00' between startopen and endopen
```

I strongly advise using something else to query that kind of data. A lot of languages already have functions to parse JSON natively.

Note to **@Karl**: how do you use REGEXP to do that. I can't see how. Thanks